# How do I write my own loop_until?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm practicing my Ruby meta-programming and trying to write my own loop method that will handle most of the ugliness in listening to a socket, but give the programmer the chance to specify the loop break condition and a block of things to do after each IO.select/sleep cycle.

What I want to be able to write is something like this:

```
x = 1
while_listening_until( x == 0 ) do
  x = rand(10)
  puts x
end
```

What I've been able to make work is:

```
def while_listening_until( params, &block )

  break_cond = params[ :condition ] || "false"
  loop {
    #other listening things are happening here
    yield
    break if params[:binding].eval( break_cond )
  }
end

x = 1
while_listening_until( :condition => "x==0", :binding => binding() ) do
  x = rand(10)
  puts x
end
```

So, how do I make all that `eval` and binding ugliness go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where lambdas are handy:

```
def while_listening_until( condition, &block )
  loop {
    #other listening things are happening here
    yield
    break if condition.call
  }
end

x = 1
while_listening(lambda{ x == 0 }) do
  x = rand(10)
  puts x
end
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thx.  Nice and clean.

Comment: When matz designed Ruby, he analyzed the Smalltalk and Lisp standard libraries and noticed that the vast majority of higher-order procedures only take a *single* procedure argument. So, he added specialized support for methods that take a single procedure argument in the form of blocks. However, when writing your *own* control structures, this assumption doesn't hold, because they usually take at least *two* procedure arguments: the *condition* and the *body*. That's why `if`, `while`, `case` and friends are keywords and not methods: because otherwise they would be ugly with all those lambdas.