# custom date range enumerator

Tags: ruby, datetime

It may sound a little stupid. But am trying to work the `yield` keyword to create a custom loop.

```
DateRange.new('2013-12-1', '2013-12-31').between do |date|
  puts date
end
```

Should result in

```
2013-12-1
2013-12-2
...
```

*DateRange* class looks like

```
class DateRange
  attr_accessor :start_date, :end_date

  def initialize(start_date, end_date)
    @start_date = Date.parse(start_date.to_s)
    @end_date = Date.parse(end_date.to_s)
  end

  def between(&block)
    yield (start_date..end_date)
  end    
end
```

Question was to iterate over `date_range` with custom block

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Question was to iterate over date_range with custom block.

Comment: down voters please support with a comment

Comment: 2013-12-31 will not work without quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the `Range` object using [Range#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html#method-i-each), and yield each item.

```
require 'date'

class DateRange
  attr_accessor :start_date, :end_date

  def initialize(start_date, end_date)
    @start_date = Date.parse(start_date.to_s)
    @end_date = Date.parse(end_date.to_s)
  end

  def between(&block)
    (start_date..end_date).each { |x|
      yield x
    }

    #    OR
    # (start_date..end_date).each &block        
  end    
end


DateRange.new('2013-12-1', '2013-12-31').between do |date|
  puts date
end
```

BTW the second argument to `DateRange.new` should be String. `2013-12-31` is `1970`.

Comment: Thanks I eventually scratched my brain to work it out

Comment: This SO post helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343103/how-do-i-write-my-own-loop-until

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with

```
def between(&block)
  (start_date..end_date).map do |date|
    yield date
  end
end
```

Comment: With `Range#map` you actually create a superfluous instance of an `Array` with values from your `Range`. You definitely want to use `Range#each` iteration here.

Comment: @mudasobwa got your point. Thanks!